# Сломанный бордер у QToolButton

Tags: css, qt, qss

Мне нужно сделать круглый QToolButton с полупрозрачным цветом бордера. Проблема появляется когда я устанавливаю QSS для этой кнопки:

```
QToolButton#someButton
{
    border: 3px solid #50dd2d9a; // any semi transparent color to border
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Основной фрагмент это установка бордеру любого полупрозрачного цвета с альфаканалом, а так же задание радиуса.

Бордер сломается как на картинке: [image: Сломанный бордер(overlap)]

Участки бордера наезжают друг на друга

Если у QToolButton убрать при этом border-radius, то бордер будет нормально работать.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Скорее всего в самом qt. похоже что это особенность обработки css

Comment: А если задать отдельно border-color и не через #... а просто, например, pink?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin К сожалению, тогда цвет будет не полупрозрачным. А именно в полупрозрачности вся проблема. Если установить любой цвет без альфа канала, то работать будет нормально

Comment: А если задать через функцию boder-color: rgba(...,150)?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Тоже самое получается. 
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(245, 176, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 20px;
Скорее всего действительно проблема в qss, в том, что участки border  рендерятся кусочками, повторяются и накладываются друг на друга при рендере, хоть это и странно

Comment: Похоже, ошибка здесь: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/gui/painting/qcssutil.cpp#L143 (строка 143). Нужно бы использовать FlatCap вместо SquareCap. Похоже на заметание какого-то другого бага. (Этот фрагмент кода не менялся  более 11 лет. Быстро найти историю этой строки я не смог.). Возможно, аналогичная ошибка при рисовании горизонтальных/вертикальных фрагментов рамки.